# The expectation of a RV with two equally likely distributions

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

I am working on this problem:

> Suppose that an observed value of *X* is equally likely to come from a continuous distribution for which the pdf is *f* or from one for which the pdf is *g*. Suppose that *f(x) > 0* for *0 < x < 1* and *f(x) = 0* otherwise, and suppose also that *g(x) > 0* for *3 < x < 6* and *g(x) = 0* otherwise. Determine **(a)** the mean and **(b)** the median of the distribution of X.

For the median, my intuition would be to just call it *0.5*F(0.5) + 0.5*G(0.5)*, treating it as a weighted probablity. But theoretically it's not clicking for me how to do that with the expectation/why that would work. Would I treat it as a conditional expectation? My thought would be to integrate *x*f(x)* from 0 to 1 and *x*g(x)* from 3 to 6, multiplying both antiderivatives by *0.5*, but I don't know how to take it farther than that without actual equations. Can someone give me a thorough explanation of what the mechanics behind this problem are? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could model $X$ as $X = S \Phi + (1-S) \Gamma$, where $S$ takes the values
$0,1$ with equal probability, $\Phi, \Gamma$ have pdfs $f,g$ respectively, and $S,\Phi,\Gamma$ are independent.

Then $E X = ES E \Phi + E (1-S) E \Gamma$, hence 
$EX = {1 \over 2} (\int x (f(x)+ g(x)) dx )$, that is,
the average of the expectations of $\Phi,\Gamma$.

The median is any number $c$ such that $P[X \le c] = {1 \over 2}$, hence
in this case we see that $P[X \le c] = {1 \over 2}$ for any $c \in [1,3]$.